# Is this the correct way to write a Boolean expression?

Tags: python, boolean

I am really confused about this one, I'm sorry if it's a stupid question.

I have a lab question that asks me to write a Boolean expression to test if the number input is in range.

Would this be the correct way to write this expression?:

```
if 1 <= number <= 10:
    True
else:
    False
```

Answer (score 2):

The `1 <= number <= 10` part is the valid *expression*; something you can evaluate and/or assign to a variable (`if` itself uses the result of the expression to alter the control flow of the program). You don't need to write `True` or `False` at all, since the test itself produces `True`/`False` as appropriate; `return 1 <= number <= 10` or `in_range = 1 <= number <= 10` is more efficient and simpler than equivalent `if`/`else` tests that explicitly perform `return True`/`return False` or `in_range = True`/`in_range = False`.

Another valid (if typically slightly slower) solution (for integers only, since, for example, `4.5` wouldn't pass this test where it would pass the former) would be:

```
number in range(1, 11)
```